# Issue while compiling an Android Project

Tags: java, android, apk

I'm trying to compile an .APK but while it builds, Android Studio generates this error:

```
Cannot get the value of a property of type java.util.Map with key type java.lang.String as the source contains a key of type java.lang.Integer.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Add the code/class where this error is generated

Comment: Please add code ...